# Add 10 hours to server time

Tags: c#, datetime

In a winform I have a string that rapresent a serial number and it is made up as following:

> PR (which is a prefix) + ss mm hh dd mm yy

which results in something like PR010110120914. Now this is the server time on which a record was saved.
This is my code where rawDate is the above string from the DB:

```
string datetimeinserver = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),
            "ssmmHHddMMyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .ToString("HH:mm:ss on dd/MM/yyy");
```

For various reasons I need to add 10 hours to datetimeinserver, I have messed around without results. Is there a simple way to add 10 hours to datetimeinserver?

Comment: `string datetimeinserver = DateTime.ParseExact` .. really?

Comment: If those 10 hours are in any way related to time zones, you ought to make that clear. If you're dealing with time zone issues, you really ought to be clear on what adjustments you're trying to make.

Comment: What's worse is the example value provided **doesn't actually parse** with the format provided in the code. It's missing a segment somewhere.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am modifying an existing code and I am trying to minimize the changes. It is dealing with the timezone but there is nothing I can do on the existing strings in the db so the easy way I see is to add the hours for the old records and resave all of them on UTC time. From there I will use UTC time regardless of the server location at least I have a unique reference.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You are correct, sorry. I sorted it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.AddHours` for that. Just change your code to this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),
        "ssmmHHddMMyy",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt = dt.AddHours(10);
string datetimeinserver = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss on dd/MM/yyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` would return you a `DateTime` object. You can then use [`DateTime.AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like:

```
DateTime tempDt = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),
                  "ssmmHHddMMyy",
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

tempDt = tempDt.AddHours(10);

string datetimeinserver = tempDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss on dd/MM/yyy");
```

You can also do the same in one statement like:

```
string datetimeinserver = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),
            "ssmmHHddMMyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            .AddHours(10)
                .ToString("HH:mm:ss on dd/MM/yyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string datetimeinserver = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),"ssmmHHddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dateTimeinserver.AddHours(10).ToString("HH:mm:ss on dd/MM/yyy");
```

?